# How do I print an object in python with its attributes?

Tags: python

```
class Check(object):
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2

    @staticmethod
    def main():
        check = Check(int(input(' : ')), int(input(' : ')))

        print(check.num1)
        print(check)

Check.main()
```

Hello, I have studied Python for about 3days.
I want to print all of the object which I inputted in the Class.
"print(check.num1)" this worked but "print(check)" it didn't work.
Please let me know how I can print all of object.

Comment: Hello. Please check your indentation, and please post the full traceback of your error. Saying "it doesn't work" isn't much to go on.

Comment: If you need just data container - use `dict` or `namedtuple`.

Comment: Please [edit] to show what you expect `print(check)` to output. And your `main` should not be part of your `Check` class. Declare it outside or separate from the class, and just call `main()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print(check)` doesn't work because python doesn't know how to print the object you created, so it prints the name of the class plus its location in memory, eg. `<__main__.Check object at 0x0000017D003F0888>`

If you want to tell the interpreter how to print an object you need to use the `__str__` magic method, like this:

```
class Check(object):
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2

    @staticmethod
    def main():
        check = Check(int(input(' : ')), int(input(' : ')))

        print(check.num1)
        print(check)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "num1={}, num2={}".format(self.num1, self.num2)

Check.main()
```

Also: are you studying from the official tutorial? if not i recommend you to check it https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html